# run high load php files without hurting server performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I want to run PHP files (which is based on MySQL queries) frequently on my server.
These files do jobs like `mysqldump` and and also calculating users rank.

High load caused by running this files hurt server performance.

Is there a way to run these files with lower priority or something?

I have seen linux "nice" command but I don't know if it affects PHP and MySQL queries too or not.

Comment: no the problem is when the file runs it causes high load. it does not matter when file is going to start.

Comment: Split your code to separate tasks and put them into separate cron scripts.

Comment: There must be a better solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Optimize your query. Make sure your tables are indexed and avoid any sub-query used inside. Interested to see if there exist any solution like u mentioned about 'nice' command.

Ok, based on your comment below. I think you should check on Big Data technologies and tools like hadoop. Mysql wont be enough to resolve your current issue.

Comment: You know what? I have done all of that, But doing some works like summing all visits of posts and images and videos of a user, Is really time consuming. what I want is streching time that program runs. I mean program stops running when load is high and countinues running when resources are free.